# Elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm looking how to merge elasticsearch hits into one. Basicly I want to do the equivalent of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE TOTO = 1 AND TATA = 2 AND TITI = 3
```

I've manage to deal with the `WHERE` part using filters but I get all the hits in separate entities 
so what I have is

```
SELECT TOTO, TATA, TITI WHERE TOTO = 1 AND TATA =2 AND TATA =3
```

How do I manage to get only one hit containing the `COUNT(*)` value ?

Environment

```
{
  "my_element": {
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "baskets": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "basket_id": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "num_basket": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "tp_basket": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "test_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "test_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so I want to count how many test element have a `basket_id` of X and a `num_basket` of 3 (if they do that means baskets are Identical, so I want also to show baskets field)

```
{
  "fields": [
    "bucket_list",
    "baskets.basket_id",
    "baskets.num_basket"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "baskets",
                "filter": {
                  "and": {
                    "filters": [
                      {
                        "or": {
                          "filters": [
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.basket_id": "40"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.num_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.tp_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.basket_id": "41"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.num_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.tp_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.basket_id": "342"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.num_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.tp_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.basket_id": "342"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.num_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "term": {
                                      "baskets.tp_basket": "1"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "baskets",
                "filter": {
                  "and": {
                    "filters": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "baskets.basket_id": "15"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "baskets.num_basket": "2"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "baskets",
                "filter": {
                  "and": {
                    "filters": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "baskets.basket_id": "15"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "baskets.num_basket": "3"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and result

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_element",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "sMHPv3i4RTqNCIChGh4Iew",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "baskets.basket_id": [
            "15",
            "15",
            "15"
          ],
          "baskets.num_basket": [
            2,
            3,
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_element",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "KL3U-g-7RtuusNV8hi9YHQ",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "baskets.basket_id": [
            "15",
            "15",
            "15"
          ],
          "baskets.num_basket": [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You've showed details related to how to be done in SQL but no details about your current ES environment. What exactly you want to count? Are these indices, types, documents? Give example from your ES environment.

Comment: Here comes the environment

Comment: And what is your query so far?

Comment: Here it is, I only have the query part and its return

Answer (score 3):

Probably I am answering really late, but for those who are looking for the answer. This query can be written in very simple way, as follows.

```
GET _count
{
"query": 
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "term" : {
        "basket_id" : "X"
      }
    }, {
      "term" : {
        "num_basket" : 3
      }
    } ]
  }
}
}
```

The above query will give you following result.

```
{
   "count": 6,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

You can read the count from above response, which is your desired result.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When the search results are returned from Elasticsearch you should see a **total** field - this has the count of matching documents.

for example, see `"total" : 2,` below:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 2.098612,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "mytest",
      "_type" : "message",
      "_id" : "P9wGgJHjQmK8GUvw8M5Q8A",
      "_score" : 2.098612,
      "fields" : {
        "tata" : [ "1" ],
        "toto" : [ "1" ],
        "titi" : [ "2" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "mytest",
      "_type" : "message",
      "_id" : "M26ychoyRR6HkordRdS_HA",
      "_score" : 0.30685282,
      "fields" : {
        "tata" : [ "1" ],
        "toto" : [ "1" ],
        "titi" : [ "2" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to have a resultset like "tata" : '1', 'toto' : 2 'titi' : 3, "cout" : 3

Comment: is **"tata":'1'** a count of matching records (i.e. only one tata record matched) or the value of the data field for tata?

Comment: it is a value of the field tata

Comment: in that case what you're asking for isn't possible - your application needs to get the data from **hits.total** not from within the **fields** object.